# index signature for KeyboardEvent typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using typescript with strict mode, we write index signature for interfaces something like this `[key: string]: any` but how should we write index signature for events like KeyboardEvent, follwing code getting error `'KeyboardEvent' has no index signature.ts(7017)`

```
public checkInput(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (event['keyIdentifier'] !== undefined) {
            keyCode = event['keyIdentifier'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the MDN [entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyIdentifier) states, this is a non-standard, deprecated feature:

> The deprecated KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier read-only property returns a "key identifier" string that can be used to determine what key was pressed. Its non-deprecated replacement is [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

If you insist on using it, you can just cast `keyIdentifier` to an appropriate key of `KeyboardEvent`:

```
public checkInput(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event['keyIdentifier' as 'key'] !== undefined) {
        const keyCode = event['keyIdentifier' as 'key'];
    }
}
```

Other options are casting to `any` (`(event as  any)['keyIdentifier']`) or augmenting the global type:

```
interface KeyboardEvent {
    keyIdentifier: string
}
class s {
    public checkInput(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (event.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
            const keyCode = event.keyIdentifier;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! i will go with `event['key'] `. Thank you.

Comment: @Urock `event.key` will work as well no need to use index access IMO